# how can i populate an array with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I would like to populate an array with all the elements found on the page with the .article-shadow class and tell it to show "none" to all elements except the first. how can I do?

https://www.grazia.it/factory/kocca-collection-la-primavera-estate-2020-e-super-glam

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    async function script() {

      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});

      //Apro il boswser, elimino la cache e setto le dimensioni della pagina
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
      page.setViewport({
      width:1920, 
      height:1080
      })

    page.on("console", msg => {
          for (let i = 0; i < msg._args.length; ++i)
            console.log(`${i}: ${msg._args[i]}`);
        }); 

      await page.goto('https://www.grazia.it/factory/kocca-collection-la-primavera-estate-2020-e-super-glam',{waitUntil:'networkidle2'}); 


    await page.waitFor(20000)

    await autoScroll(page);


    async function autoScroll(page){
      await page.evaluate(async () => {
          await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              var totalHeight = 0;
              var distance = 100;

              var timer = setInterval(() => {
                  var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                  window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                  totalHeight += distance;

                  if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                      clearInterval(timer);
                      resolve();
                  }
              }, 100);
          });
      });
    }





   const articles = await page.$$(".article-shadow");
  console.log('before FOR');
  for (let z = 1; z < articles.length; z++){
    console.log(articles[z]+'ARTICLES');
    console.log(articles[z].getProperty("style"));
    //articles[z].style.display = 'none';
  }

    // Scroll back to top
    await page.evaluate(_ => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });




    //Salvo lo screenshot
    await page.screenshot({path: './screenshot.jpg', fullPage: true}); //
    console.log('Screenshot salvato con successo! :)');

    //Fine
    await page.close();
    browser.close();

    } //end if (urlArray[i].indexOf("http") != '-1'){  

    }//fine ciclo

    }; //end scriptMacOs


    script();
```

unfortunately it gives me this error...
(node:7756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: document is not defined

[image]

Comment: Where is your puppeteer code? You can't do this on the document, you have to call your methods on the launched puppeteer browser page.

Comment: hi, I entered all the code of the script! :)
I wish I could disable all the articles that follow the first one to be able to save the screenshot without the infinite scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't use any methods of `document`, as you don't run in the browser and so document is undefined. You need to use the methods of `page` instead. You can use either [$](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector), which will run the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method or [$$](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args), which will run [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). $$ has as second argument a callback function, which will be fired when the nodes are found. So you could do:

```
const articles = await page.$$(".article-shadow", articles => {
  for (let z = 1; z < articles.length; z++){
    articles[z].style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

You can get the pages `console.logs` by mapping them to your console with this function:

```
  page.on("console", msg => {
      for (let i = 0; i < msg._args.length; ++i)
        console.log(`${i}: ${msg._args[i]}`);
    });
```

Comment: thanks bro! seems not to take the display = 'none'. in the screenshot I see all the printed articles. could it take longer before taking the screenshot?

Comment: Can you `console.log` the articles? If they are there than maybe you need a timeout before taking the screenshot.

Comment: putting a simple console.log in the loop for, nothing happens, not even the console.log exits into the console

Comment: Did you map the pages console to your dev console? If not, I updated my answer with code so that you can do it.

Comment: Did you add the `page.on` listener to your code? I don't understand the last comment.

Comment: sorry, I'm learning a little at a time and I have little experience :) where should I insert this code?

Comment: No problem. Add it before `page.goto`. Your problem is that puppeteer simulates a browser and without this mapping, all the console logs in your code will happen in the simulated browsers dev tools. By mapping your console to them, they will be forwarded to you.

Comment: ok understood, I put your script above everything and it gives me back everything that is loaded on the page.

Comment: ok, it gave me a lot written in console.log but I have not found the console.log that I inserted in the for loop to read how many articles it found. I inserted a screenshot to make you understand better at the top of my post.

Comment: Strange. Try to remove the callback and do this instead: `const articles = await page.$$(".article-shadow");console.log(articles);`.

Comment: ok! now gives me my console.log (before for) but still nothing, I updated the screenshot above the post so you can see the problem.

Comment: Well, as we see from your `console.log`, articles exist. It seems like `style` does not exist on the item. So the next step is to console.log the article with `console.log(articles[z]);` in the loop.

Comment: ok! updated screenshot! now I see the console.log. what do you recommend to do now?

Comment: As it is a *jshandle* you can use it's api methods: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#jshandlejsonvalue 
You should be able to access the style with `articles[z].getProperty("style");`. You can console log it first to see whether it works and then try to update it.

Comment: updated screenshot! now gives me Promise {<pending>}

Answer (score 0):

```
const articles = document.getElementsByClassName('article-shadow');
for (let z = 1; z < articles.length; z ++){
  articles[z].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: (node:22389) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.